# Expected value of the zeros of random polynomials of degree two

Tags: probability-theory, polynomials, expectation

Let $a_1,a_0$ be i.i.d. real random variables with uniform distribution in $[-1,1]$. I'm interested in the random zeros of the polynomial $$p(x) = x^2 + a_1x + a_0. $$

One thing (between many) thing I'm particularly interested is in computing the expected value of it's zeros. It's possible to write exactly what are the zeros $z_1,z_2$ of $p(x)$, they are
$$ z_1 = \frac{-a_1+\sqrt{a_1^2-4a_0}}{2} $$
and
$$ z_2 = \frac{-a_1-\sqrt{a_1^2-4a_0}}{2}. $$

Therefore what I want is to calculate $$E[z_1] = E\Bigg[\frac{-a_1+\sqrt{a_1^2-4a_0}}{2}\Bigg] = \frac{-E[a_1] + E\Big[{\sqrt{a_1^2-4a_0}}\Big]}{2} = \frac{E\Big[{\sqrt{a_1^2-4a_0}}\Big]}{2}.$$

Note that I only need to calculate $E[z_1]$, for $E[z_2] = \overline{E[z_1]}$. Also, doing some experimentation with Matlab, it looks like $E[z_1] = i$.

I want to confirm that result with a mathematical proof, if possible. Thank you.

**Edit:** From my own computation, we can see that the correct relation between the expected values should be $E[z_2] = -E[z_1]$, not $E[z_2] = \overline{E[z_1]}$.

Comment: I don't think it's possible for your result to be correct, since $\operatorname{Re}(E\Big[{\sqrt{a_1^2-4a_0}}\Big])=E\Big[\operatorname{Re}(\sqrt{a_1^2-4a_0})\Big]>0$.

Comment: How do you get that inequality? It doesn't look obvious at all.

Comment: The real part of the expectation is the same as the expectation of the real part. But the real part of the square root is sometimes positive and never negative, so its expectation must be positive.

Comment: Depending on your purpose, you might get more insight separating the case or real roots from the case of complex roots.  The real root (positive square root) case is a density on the segment $[-1/2, (1/2)(1+\sqrt{5})]$.  The complex root (positive square root) case is a density on the part of the unit disk with positive imaginary part and real part in $[-1/2,1/2]$.  Looking at the negative square roots gives the negative interval and the conjugate region, respectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$E[z_1]=\frac{E\Big[{\sqrt{a_1^2-4a_0}}\Big]}2\\=\frac18\left(\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{x^2-4y}dydx\right)\\=\frac1{48}\left(\int_{-1}^1(x^2+4)^{\frac32}-(x^2-4)^{\frac32}dx\right)\\=\frac1{24}\left(\int_0^1(4+x^2)^\frac32dx+i\int_0^1(4-x^2)^\frac32dx\right)\\=\frac{1}{24}\left(\left(\frac{11\sqrt5}4+6\sinh^{-1}\frac12\right)+i\left(\frac{9\sqrt3}4+\pi\right)\right)\\\approx0.3765+0.2933i$$

Answer (score 2):

Let the roots be the random variables $U$ and $V$. Then by symmetry $E(U)=E(V)$. But $U+V=-a_1$, so $U+V$ has mean $0$. Thus $E(U)=E(V)=0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what symmetry are you talking about?

Comment: There is no symmetry, because one root is defined with the positive square root and the other is defined with the negative square root. In particular, $\operatorname{Im}(z_1)\ge0$.

Comment: OK, let's use the quadratic formula. By the linearity of expectation, $E((-a_1+\sqrt{D})/2 +(-a_1+\sqrt{D})/2))=E(-a_1)$.

Comment: I agree that $U+V$ has mean $0$ but can't see how $E(U) = E(V)$.

Comment: OK, then use the quadratic formula version. Or think that when we have produced the two roots, we randomly choose one of them.

Comment: @AndréNicolas But you don't randomly choose one of them. They are defined so that $\operatorname{Re}(z_1)\ge\operatorname{Re}(z_2)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(z_1)\ge\operatorname{Im}(z_2)$

Comment: From the title, it looked as if it was expected value of the zeros that was asked for, and not the expected value with restriction.

Comment: However, for $z_1$ as defined it looks like a doable integration.