# Expected root of quadratic random polynomial

Tags: probability, polynomials, uniform-distribution

Suppose $A,B,C$ are i.i.d. random variables with uniform distribution on $[-1,1]$. I'm interested in the expected roots of the polynomial $Ax^2 + Bx + C$, which are complex random variables given by
$$Z_1 = \frac{-B+\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}$$
and
$$Z_2 = \frac{-B-\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}.$$

Making simulations, I computed 
$$E[Z_1] \approx 0.3559 + 0.0005i$$ 
and 
$$E[Z_2] \approx -0.6421 - 0.0005i.$$

To confirm this resuts, I need to calculate this values mathematically. For $E[Z_1]$ for instance, this means to calculate the integral 
$$\frac{1}{8}\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1  \frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\ da\ db\ dc.$$

Unfortunately, looks like this integral has different values when we change the order of integration. I tried to compute with Wolframalpha. It gives me zero or can't compute depending on the order. Probably this is because the term $\frac{1}{2a}$ goes to infinity in the interval of integration, so we can't use Fubini's Theorem. I'm not sure if Wolframalpha just failed to compute some integrals or $E[Z_1]$ is really not defined. This second scenario means $Z_1$ has no expected value, so the random polynomial $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ has no expected root. I think this is a strange scenario, therefore I really need to confirm whether this is the case or not.

Thanks!

Comment: The litterature on the subject is very vast, beginning in the 1950s with pioneering works by the extraordinary Mark Kac. Have you explored it a little ? Have a look at the recent article (http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.4357) by no less extraordinary mathematician (and Fields medalist) Terence Tao.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the advice. In fact, I know about Kac's relevance and this article. Still, what I'm asking is far less general and simple enough to have an explicitly answer by elementary means.

Comment: you can normalize the equation since only the ratios B/A and C/A matter for root computation.  This also eliminates the case where A=0 (becomes a first degree equation).

Comment: @karakfa What do you mean by *normalize* ?

Comment: represent the quadratic as $x^2+bx+c$, that is $b=B/A,$ and $c=C/A$.

Comment: @karakfa Ok, that was my first approach. If i set $z_1 = \frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4c}}{2}$, the idea is that $E[z_1] = E[Z_1]$, right? The problem is that my simulations shows this is not true (I made one million simulations). What I got is $E[Z1] \approx 0.3559+0.0005i$ and $E[z_1] \approx 0.3765+0.2933i$. In fact, the mathematical computation of $E[z_1]$ is made in another post of mine: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1856626/expected-value-of-the-zeros-of-random-polynomials-of-degree-two

Comment: They are different.  Your formulation has 3 degrees of freedom, but you should have two.

Comment: I don't get why I should have two. All I really want the expected root of $Ax^2+Bx+C$, not $x^2+bx+c$. If they are different and the latter is computable, I see no problem in trying to compute the former. Also, I still don't understand how normalizing would help me to compute $E[Z_1]$.

Comment: Perhaps, comparing first degree equations will help. Expected root of $Ax+B$ vs $x+b$.

Comment: The first one, E[-b/a] will give me a not convergent integral. The second one is $E[-b] = 0.$ Are you saying me that the expected roots of $Ax^2+Bx+C$ are not well defined because the integral will not converge?

Comment: A problem induced by normalisation is that $b=B/A$ and $c=C/A$ are not independent ; but one take into account this non independence.

Comment: Have you thought that knowing the roots is equivalent to knowing their sum S and their product P, but, these are precisely $-B/A$ and $C/A$ resp. , i.e., (up to a sign) the normalized variables...